# Category of constructible rings

Tags: limits, ring-theory, category-theory

I wonder if a category of constructible rings does make sense and how it differs from the complete [category of rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_rings) resp. how it could be completed.

Let the objects $\mathcal{O}$ of this category be recursively defined by

- $\mathbb{C} \in \mathcal{O}$
- $\mathcal{R} \in \mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{R}'$ a subring of $\mathcal{R}$ $\rightarrow $  $\mathcal{R}' \in \mathcal{O}$
- $\mathcal{R} \in \mathcal{O}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $\rightarrow $  $M_n(\mathcal{R}) \in \mathcal{O}$ ([matrix ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_ring))
- $\mathcal{R} \in \mathcal{O}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$$\rightarrow $  $\mathcal{R}[X_1,\dots,X_n] \in \mathcal{O}$ ([polynomial ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring))
- $\mathcal{R} \in \mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{R}$ is an integral domain $\rightarrow $ $\operatorname{Quot}(\mathcal{R}) \in \mathcal{O}$ ([field of fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions))
- $\mathcal{R} \in \mathcal{O}$ and $I$ is a two-sided ideal in $\mathcal{R}$ $\rightarrow $  $\mathcal{R}/I \in \mathcal{O}$ ([quotient ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring))
- $\mathcal{R} \in \mathcal{O}$, $\mathcal{R}$ a subring of $\mathcal{R}'$ and $x \in \mathcal{R}'$ $\rightarrow $  $\mathcal{R}[x] \in \mathcal{O}$ (extension)

Is this list of constructions complete in a way? Which other constructions are relevant for building up a category of constructible rings? The other way around:

> Which "natural" rings would one expect to be constructible but could
>   not be constructed by the rules above?

I assume that by these constructions the p-adic rings [$\mathbb{Z}_p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number), [$\mathbb{Q}_p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) would **not** be in the category of constructible rings, while $\mathbb{R}$ **is** because it's a subring of $\mathbb{C}$.

> Can in a way a completed category of rings be obtained from a
>   restricted category of constructible rings by adding all "limits"?

(I've [learned](http://www1.spms.ntu.edu.sg/~frederique/antchap5.pdf) that $\mathbb{Z}_p = \lim_{\leftarrow} \mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ where all quotient rings $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ are in $\mathcal{O}$.)

Comment: This might be a silly question, but does $R[z]$ always make sense for a complex $z$?

Comment: Oh no, obviously not silly! My idea was silly! How may I rescue it?

Comment: I am not sure. What sort of rings do you want in your category, which are only "constructible" by that rule?\

Comment: I rewrote the question. Now the term "constructible" is not so appropriate anymore because already in the first rule you take all subrings of $\mathbb{C}$ which is not very constructive. And you probably don't need the field-of-fractions rule anymore, because $\mathbb{Q} \in \mathcal{O}$ already by the subring-rule, so you don't need to add it by $\mathbb{Q} = \operatorname{Quot}(\mathbb{Z})$ anymore.

Comment: The same holds for the quotient-ring rule.

Comment: The most useful thing I can contribute to this very speculative question is that given a ring, the class of rings 'constructible' via square matrix rings and corner rings (i.e. making the ring eRe using a full idempotent e in R) results in precisely the class of rings Morita equivalent to $R$.

Comment: And also that maybe if your 'constructions' are "forming F[x]" and "taking a quotient" then the class of rings constructible should be all finitely generated F algebras.

Comment: @rschwieb: Thanks, that helps a lot.

Comment: As it almost always is, hoping one has found "the complete list of stuff you can do" is an untenable question.  But it seems there are really useful special cases.

Comment: Seconding what has been said above, your second rule as currently written (that all subrings of a constructible set are constructible) is _much_ too generous; for instance, not all subsets of a constructible set are constructible, etc. Depending on what you want your specific notion of 'constructible' to be, you might want that to be those 'finitely generated' in some suitable sense within $\mathcal{R}$, or something similar.

Comment: Also, I'm surprised no one has mentioned this yet, but you don't want the word 'category' for this construction; that's a specific technical term, and while you're currently talking about the objects you've said nothing about morphisms. I think you're looking for the _class_ (actually, probably set) of constructible rings, by whatever definition you use.

Comment: I just assumed ring homomorphisms between all "constructible" rings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}_p$ is in your category for a fairly non-obvious reason: actually it already arises in the very second step, as a subring of $\mathbb{C}$. $\mathbb{C}$ has a *lot* of subrings. In fact:

> Up to isomorphism, the subrings of $\mathbb{C}$ are precisely the integral domains of characteristic zero with cardinality at most that of $\mathbb{C}$.

*Proof.* If $D$ is such a domain, the algebraic closure of its fraction field is an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero which is at most uncountable, and up to isomorphism, algebraically closed fields of characteristic zero are determined by their cardinality. In particular there is a unique countable one, namely $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, and a unique one with cardinality $\mathbb{C}$, namely $\mathbb{C}$ itself. $\Box$

On the other hand, none of your constructions increase the cardinality of a ring beyond the cardinality of $\mathbb{C}$, so your category does not include any ring with a larger cardinality. I know of no really natural examples of such rings but we can take, for example, the ring $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$.

A speculation: among the steps you've listed, only the construction of matrix rings makes a ring "more noncommutative," and for that reason I think, although I'm not sure, that "very noncommutative" rings such as the [Weyl algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_algebra) can't be constructed this way.

The most important construction which doesn't explicitly appear on your list, although it can be done to some extent using the constructions on your list, is probably [localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring).

---

As for the more general question of how to generate rings, for general categorical reasons, every ring can be constructed from the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ by repeatedly taking [colimits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/colimit). In fact it suffices to be able to take coproducts, which here are [free products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product_of_associative_algebras), and coequalizers. Somewhat more explicitly, every ring is a quotient of a noncommutative polynomial ring on a sufficiently large number of generators by a suitable two-sided ideal, which is to say that every ring has a presentation by generators and relations, just as for groups. There are other ways of splitting this up; for example, again for general categorical reasons, every ring is a [filtered colimit](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/filtered+limit) of finitely presented rings.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What gives me a lot to think about: "**Every** ring can be constructed from the ring **$\mathbb{Z}[x]$** by repeatedly taking **colimits**." This sounds unbelievable (for the beginner).

Comment: @HansStricker $\mathbb Z[x]$ is the free ring on one generator. Call it $F1$ where $F$ is the free ring functor and $1$ is the one element set. $F$ is a left adjoint so it preserves colimits and thus coproducts. Every set is a coproduct (i.e. disjoint union) of one element sets, so $FS\cong\coprod_SF1=\coprod_S\mathbb Z[x]$. Every ring is a quotient of a free ring. In the worst-case scenario, if we have a ring $R$, we take the free ring on the underlying set of $R$ and quotient it by the relation that identifies two non-commutative "polynomials" when they "evaluate" to the same element of $R$.